# Jekyll: liquid tags shown when hosted on GitHub

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I'm just getting started with `Jekyll` and I managed to do some cool stuff locally - i.e. when I locally serve the page and open it on my browser, everything works fine.

However when I pushed everything on GitHub, I see the actual `liquid` tags on my pages, and not what they're supposed to stand for.

I'm not even sure of how I can debug this, as locally everything looks fine. I made sure my local and remote repositories are synced.

Thanks!

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION** - `HTML` and `CSS` are rendered properly, and the `Jekyll` frontmatter seems to be doing its job by pointing to the correct layouts. It's only the liquid tags that don't seem to be working. I did have `liquid` tags working just fine on initial tests I did directly on the remote repository (very basic stuff like showing titles, dates, etc), but after pushing things I wrote (and successfully tested) locally, it seems like they are not being correctly interpreted anymore.

Comment: https://github.com/a-silvia/a-silvia.github.io; should have thought of posting this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your three `_layouts`, add a `<meta charset="UTF-8">` just after the opening `<head>`.

In `_layouts/default.html` and `_layouts/timeline.html` change `{{ page.content }}` to `{{ content }}`.

In `_includes/timeline.html` remove `{{ page.content | markdownify }}`.